# Background color of table cell changes depending on 2 conditions

Tags: colors, pine-script

i would like to change the background color of a cell. The change will depend on 2 conditions, if the final value of cell is >20 then green, if less than -20 then red.

```
    table.cell(panel, 5, 0, str.tostring(finalvalue), bgcolor=close>20?color.green:color.red)'
```

I managed the first condition but how can I add the second condition pls

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
bgcolor=close>20?color.green:color.red)
```

Will change the backround to green if the close price is above 20 and to red otherwise.

What you need is a second ternary operator in this condition.

```
bgcolor = finalvalue > 20 ? color.green : finalvalue < -20 color.red : color.yellow)
```

In this statement, the background will be **green** if `finalvalue` is greater than 20, and it will be **red** if it is less than -20 and it will be **yellow** if it is in between.

Comment: thanks for your reply!
Instaed of doing your suggestion cell by cell, is there a code that will do the color change on the whole table pls?

Comment: I am getting the error Syntax error at input '(':------->
    table.cell(panel, 5, 0, str.tostring(finalvalue), bgcolor = finalvalue> 20 ? color.green : finalvalue< -20 color.red : color.yellow)

What am i doing wrong?